# Get the numbers inside two spans and do a calculation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a wordpress plugin that outputs some numbers into span elements.
I would like to get the values of these span elements and divide the one with the other, then display the result somewhere on the site.
I don't know much about javascript, and have tried some samples online, but can't get them to work. Can anyone please explain how this can be done?

Also note, these span elements doesn't have their own ID's, and because this is used in a plugin, I can't edit these directly, so I'll need to target them like this in order to target each span individually:

```
.container1 .tooltip span
.container2 .tooltip span
```

Comment: What plugin are you using? Does it give you any events you can hook to when the values change?

Comment: nobody will be able to help you unless you post some related HTML.

Comment: This platform is not for ready to use script. Please be specific what you have tried and where you stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseInt()` if values don't have decimals:

```
var a = parseInt($('.container1 .tooltip span').text(), 10);
var b = parseInt($('.container2 .tooltip span').text(), 10);

console.log(a - b);
```

use `parseFloat().toFixed(2);` if values have decimals:

```
var a = parseFloat($('.container1 .tooltip span').text()).toFixed(2);
var b = parseFloat($('.container2 .tooltip span').text()).toFixed(2);

console.log(a - b);
```

Prefixing `+` can also change the string number `"0"` value to number `0` not this one `"$0"`.

```
var a = +$('.container1 .tooltip span').text();
var b = +$('.container2 .tooltip span').text();

console.log(a - b);
```

---

<sub>More can be answered if you add details about the tooltip.</sub>

Comment: what if `<span>12,34</span>` or `<span>12.34</span>`?

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be close to what I need. Any chance you can create a fiddle for me? How will I print it to HTML?

Comment: You can change `console.log(a - b);` to `$('targetElement').text(a - b);`

Comment: @Shtarley what if the values are as per comment of GeneR. Has that possibility there.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far Jai. I am very new to javascript, so I don't understand what you mean - How do I get the result to show in my HTML? Must I target the ID of a div or how does it work?

Comment: @Shtarley yes suppose you have a div with id `result` then you can do `$('#result').text(a - b);` to put the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the `.value` from each element and then divide them using a function like this which feeds the result to a new element:

```
function divideBy() { 
    num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 / num2;
}
```

[Check out this demo](http://jsbin.com/wosubozojo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this snippet:

1. Collect Values
2. do Something with them

```js
function SumCtrl() {
  var resultView = document.getElementById('result');
  
  var values = (function(nodeList) {
    if(!nodeList) { return []; }
    var res = [];
    
    for (var i = nodeList.length >>> 0; i--;) { 
      res[i] = nodeList[i].textContent;
    }
    
    return res.map(function(i) { return Number(i) || 0; });
  })(document.querySelectorAll('div span'));
  
  resultView.innerHTML = values
    .reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', SumCtrl);
```

```html
<h1 id="result"></h1>

<div class="something">
  <span>1</span>
</div>
<div class="something1">
  <span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="something2">
  <span>3</span>
</div>
<div class="something3">
  <span>4</span>
</div>
```